# Making extension always opened once the user clicked in the extension icon, only close when the extension icon is clicked

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want my extension, once it is opened (clicked on the icon), to only be closed when the user click on my extension icon , like it happens when you have developer mode on and 'Inspect Pop-up', when it's in developer mode you can only close your extension after you click in the icon of it in the chrome.

I would like to make it visible until the user click on the extension icon (not any click outside) to close it but without having to have the developer mode on.

or if this is not possible I would like to at least once my extension is clicked, make my extension active so it can deal with the `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener()`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "deal with"? Is it that you want to add a listener when the extension button is clicked?

Comment: yes I want to use the addListener , but the problem is when the user clicks outside the html area of the extension, the onBeforeRequest is disabled since it is like the complement isn't being used anymore. I want to make the addListener active while the user uses other webpages, change tabs and everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [background pages](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html#example). As the documentation says a background page is

> a single long-running script to manage some task or state

It should work if your aim is to achieve such a task.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, [Desktop Notifications](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/notifications.html) are some kind of decision.